# MySQL InnoDB Full-text search: Override default stopword list

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, query-optimization, innodb

I'm using MySQL8.0 InnoDB and its full-text search features. The default stopwords list of InnoDB only contains 36 words. Extending the stopword list to 500+ words helps to lift our full-text queries speed a lot.

The problem is according to this [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), we will need to `SET GLOBAL config innodb_ft_server_stopword_table = 'test/my_stopwords'`. However, our team doesn't have the DB super user right and we cannot modify the stopword table config. The workaround I have found is to `SET SESSION config innodb_ft_user_table = 'test/my_stopwords'`, and rebuild FULLTEXT index within the same session.

But the limitations of this workaround is that whenever we did a DB cleanup, or even whenever we update/insert new data, it won't be using the customized stopword table, and we will have to set the SESSION config and rebuild FULLTEXT index again. (I assume existing data's index built with the customized stopword table shouldn't be impacted even if the session is closed?)

Is there any other ways to use the customized stopword table without the GLOBAL config?

Two solutions to this problem I can think of:

1. SET SESSION config and rebuild FULLTEXT index time to time, whenever there is a DB cleanup, or when search is performing noticeable slow.
2. In our code, before executing any full-text queries, read the customized stopword table and toss any stopword in the search string and only search remaining words.

Comment: Either workaround sounds tolerable. Both sound wasteful. Sometimes the hardest part of data management is management, isn't it?

Comment: Do you need any help yet?